# Cannot create symlink in magento

Tags: magento2, grunt

I installed grunt and run command **grunt exec:my theme** but it shows me

> > [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
> >       Cannot create a symlink for "C:/xampp/htdocs/packt/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_reset.l
> >       ess" and place it to "C:/xampp/htdocs/packt/pub/static/frontend/gog/gogparent/en_US/css/source/_reset.less" Wa
> >       rning!symlink(): Cannot create symlink, error code(1314)

( gog is my custom theme )
I checked **di.xml** in app/etc folder and in **virtualTypename="developerMaterialization"** section ,content is

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

then I **clean cache** and Delete the files under **pub/static**,but error still showing when I run command.what can I do with this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Please open the cmd window as **administrator**. Right click on CMD then "Run as Administrator" then run your **grunt commands** and it will work !